# создание новой записи в gorm

Tags: sql, golang, orm, gorm

Я пытаюсь созадть модель в базе данных через `GetDB().Create(&user)`, где `GetDB` возращает *gorm.DB, а user экхемпляр модели User:

```
type User struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Login    string
    Password string
}
```

Однако, я получаю ошибку:
`cmd/db/user.go:8 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.id`

Comment: видимо, 2 раза попытались создать таблицу. верно?

Comment: Нет. Я понимаю что ошибка из за того что существует ключ. Но как сделать что бы он автоматически увеличивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, PK тоже указывается перед сохранением. Это не нужно делать. все тэги primaryKey [по умолчанию](https://gorm.io/docs/composite_primary_key.html#content-inner) являются AutoIncrement=true. можно указать тэг `autoIncrement`, чтобы GORM понимал ее суть. Но значение для ключа передавать не нужно.

```
package model

import (
    `github.com/jinzhu/gorm`
)

type TestModel struct {
    MyId int64 `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment;not_null"`
    Name string
}

func ModelSave(tx *gorm.DB) {
    tm := TestModel{Name:"Test the model"}
    tx.Save(&tm)
}
```

запускаем пару раз и получаем

```
MariaDB [gmodel]> select * from test_models;
+-------+----------------+
| my_id | name           |
+-------+----------------+
|     1 | Test the model |
|     2 | Test the model |
+-------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: а забираю структуру из Json. Мне надо как то удалить поле id из неё?

Comment: тут зависит какое поведение хотите. можете создать с указанным ID, если получили ошибку, то отвечайте на запрос ошибкой. если не хотите этот ID использовать, но удалите его